# ajax set result to a variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I assign results from Ajax call into a variable?

I have a drop down list. when user make a choice. I want ajax to call a PHP page to find related data from server and auto fill that into an input field.

See below code

```
$(document).on('change','#dropdownchoiceid', function(){
        $id = 1; // passing in some variable for php to use
        $.ajax({

            url: "../folder/getdata.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'id' : $id
            },
            success:function(data){
                $result = data; 
                console.log($result);
                $('#inputid').val($result.column1);
                $('#inputid2').val($result.column2);
            }
        });
```

The php is working. I get the result in a object that look like this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["column1"]=>
    string(7) "20.0000"
    ["column2"]=>
    string(14) "someinfo"
    ["column3"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

So I am trying to change the input field value with the datas I got from the server. but I get blanks in the console.log. I dont quite understand the code below. I tried it because I see this answer on stackoverflow for similar questions

```
success:function(data){
                $result = data; 

            }
```

the PHP is

```
<?php

//Create class Object
$mProduct = new mProduct;

$id = $_POST['id'];

$result= $mProduct->getData($id);
```

the model PHP page is

```
public function getData($id){
    $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM rebate
    WHERE id= :id
    ");
    //bind
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
    //Assign Result Set
    $result = $this->db->resultset();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code returning the data from server-side (PHP)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668290/jquery-javascript-store-ajax-jsonp-response-into-variables  I tried solution on this page, does not seem to change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hard-coded an array to match what your db methods returned, according to your var_dump,
in your PHP page:

```
$arr=(object) [  "id"=> "2", "column1"=>"20.0000", "column2"=>"someinfo", column3"=>"1" ];
$arr=array($arr);
//var_dump($arr);
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Also, I suggest that use echo instead of print_r because

> print_r will also show protected and private properties of objects with PHP 5.
>   [See PHP Manual print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Initialize your $result variable and since it is an array with a single element
you must reference it that way:

```
$.ajax({

        url: "getData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'id' : $id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            var $result = data; // var initialize
            console.log($result);
           $('#inputid').val($result[0].column1); //$result is an array
           $('#inputid2').val($result[0].column2);

        },
        error:function(data){
           window.alert("Something went wrong"+data.error);
        }
    });
```

You ask: 
(Quote)...is the word data supposed to match the $result from my PHP page?
..data is the variable on the client side that the server response gets stored in

Answer (score 1):

To receive data on front end, the PHP page has to print something, preferably in [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) format. Try this:

```
<?php

//Create class Object
$mProduct = new mProduct;

$id = $_POST['id'];

$result= $mProduct->getData($id);

print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: Hi Erik, it is getting close. the console shows the result if I print_r the $result in PHP page, with json encode I get same info in a different format. but my javascript is not doing anything

Comment: Hm, perhaps you need to use JSON.parse(data) on front end, give it a try.

Comment: I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A. if I put json.parse(data) in the $result = data part.

Comment: Try adding 'dataType': 'json' to your $.ajax call

Comment: does not seem to change anything. also success:function(data){
                $result = data; 

            } where is the data coming from. is the word data supposed to match the $result from my PHP page?

Comment: hm strange :/
"data" is simply the return value from the success function, it can be named anything

Answer (score 0):

I am OP answering my own question.

[Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)

after checking above post. here is the answer

so the final working code look like this

```
 $(document).on('change','#dropdownchoiceid', function(){
    $id = 1; // passing in some variable for php to use
    $.ajax({

        url: "../folder/getdata.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'id' : $id
        },
        datatype: "json",
        success:function(data){
            $result = data; 
            console.log($result);
            $('#inputid').val($result.column1);
            $('#inputid2').val($result.column2);
        }
    });
```

in PHP

add one more line

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: console.log($result); not needed, it is for testing